# Kant claimed that 7+5=12 is a synthetic proposition; is this not obvious?

Tags: logic, epistemology

Whenever anyone claims that 7+5=12 is an analytic proposition, they are overlooking one important detail. What is that? Charles M. Saunders

Comment: Someone claimed that it is analytic because can be derived by way of logic from definitions; see [Logicism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logicism/).

Comment: No, what Kant calls "synthetic" and "analytic" is rather vague and obscure. It is also different from what they mean today, and from what different schools think they *should* mean, regardless of Kant. It takes some length just to sort out all the clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Kant, the proposition "7+5=12" was obviously synthetic for no logical analysis of the concept of " the sum of 7 and of 5 " will ever yield the result " equal to 12".

According to Kant, the logical analysis of " 7+5" may yield "7+5 = 7+5" or, at best " 7+5 = 5+7" , but it will never yield "7+5 = 12".

One argument could be : the " concept " sum of 7 and of 5" can be decomposed logivcally in 3 parts (1) concept of a sum , (2) concept of number 5 units (3) concept of 7 units.

I clearly see that the concept " number 12 " is not contained logically in the original concept. You will never find "12" in " sum" nor in " 5" nor in "7"?

From this, Kant draws the conclusion that , logical analysis ( decomposition) being unable to yield the result "12", only synthesis ( litterally, "com-position") could bring the result.

The result has to be " constructed" in the pure intuition of space/ time : I have to construct the object corresponding to my concept of a sum, I have to go out of my concept and build a 12 unit number out of 7 and of 5 in order to know that " 7+5 =12". Only this synthetic process will teach me that " adding 7 and 5 " is the same thing as adding 12 times a unit to 0.

But is all this " obvious"?

This is obvious if and only if one takes as granted Kant's conception of logical analysis, and in particular Kant's logical analysis of the concept " sum of 7 and of 5".

Modern mathematics shows that

(1) with the definiiton of 7 and of 5

and (2) the definition of " sum of a and of b " as

> a+b = a if b=O  and a + successor of b = successor of (a+b)

it can be logically shown that " 7+5 " is logically identical to "12" ( that is, to " successor of 11").

So analysing "7+5" as " 7+ successor of 4" = "successor of (7+4) " , etc. allows to derive logically the result "12".

This really challenges Kants conception of " 7+5=12" and mades far less obvious his claim according to which this proposiiton is synthetic.

The burden of proof actually lies on Kant ( whose conception is paradoxical) rather than on his adversaries ( such as Leibniz or Wolff).

Comment: @Eleanore Saint James- splendid response, thank you for the thoughtful and complete explication. Look for my next question, on proportionality today. CMS